# In fabric.js ( react.js) how can i add canvas objects on onClick?

Tags: reactjs, fabricjs

It works if I adds the code into useEffect but on onClick no object is showing.
I want to show canvas objects on onClick.

```
   import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { fabric } from 'fabric';

const Canvasbody = () => {
const canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas-main');

  function RectB(canvi) {
    const rect = new fabric.Rect({
      height: 280,
      width: 200,
      fill: 'yellow',
    });

    canvi.add(rect);
  }
  return (
    <>
      <canvas
        style={{ border: 'solid 1px #555' }}
        id="canvas-main"
        width="600px"
        height="600px"
      />

      <button onClick={() => RectB(canvas)}>Click me</button>
    </>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `canvi.renderAll()` after adding `rect` to `canvas` in your function.